# How to match the string in the URL and split the URL from the index of matched string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an **URL** like: `/path/id/anotherpath/0`

From the above **URL** I have to check if `anotherpath` exists, and split the part of **URL** from `/anotherpath`, so I want to get only `/anotherpath/0` from the **URL**.

I tried using:

```javascript
const path = this.props.location.pathname;

if (path.indexOf(anotherpath > 0) {
    path = path.split('anotherpath');
}
```

but the above gives me a splitted **URL** like `/path/id` and `/0`. How can I fix this? I want to get the **URL** from `anotherpath` to the last part of the **URL**.

Comment: `if (path.indexOf(anotherpath >0)` ?? I think you mean `if (path.indexOf("anotherpath") > 0)`

Comment: you just need a `[0]` (before the term) or a `[1]` (after the term) to turn your array of splits into the string you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using regular expression.

```js
let path = "/path/id/anotherpath/0"
path = path.split(/(\/anotherpath)/).slice(1).join('')
console.log(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution is to use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from the `indexOf("anotherpath")`

```js
const path = "/path/id/anotherpath/0";
const idx = path.indexOf("anotherpath");

if (idx > 0)
    console.log(path.slice(idx - 1));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Another alternative is to use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const path = "/path/id/anotherpath/0";
let res = path.match(/\/anotherpath.*/);
console.log(res ? res[0] : "not found");
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding the question correctly, path.substring(path.indexOf("/anotherpath")) would give you just the desired part of the string

you'd also need to declare path as a let, as you are reassigning it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function similar to the following. This function receives a path as an argument and if the token you are looking for exists, it will cut it and return only the section that interests you, otherwise it will return the complete path

```
function getSubpath(path) {
    if (!path.includes('anotherpath')) return path;

    const tokens = path.split('/');
    const index = tokens.findIndex(token => token === 'anotherpath');

    tokens.splice(0, index);

    return `/${tokens.join('/')}`;
}
```

Please try the following implementation

```js
// having these variables
const path0 = '/path/id/0';
const path1 = '/path/id/anotherpath/0';

function getSubpath(path) {
    if (!path.includes('anotherpath')) return path;

    const tokens = path.split('/');
    const index = tokens.findIndex(token => token === 'anotherpath');

    tokens.splice(0, index);

    return `/${tokens.join('/')}`;
}

console.log(getSubpath(path0));
console.log(getSubpath(path1));
```